# Design view of android text box width, height and text size

Tags: android

this is my code what i'm showing here:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:weightSum="80" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:textSize="18px"
        android:text="India is best"                     
        android:layout_weight="20" />
</TableRow>
```

but display is not proper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..dn't specify edittext height in px.always use dp for width and height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:weightSum="80" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="India is best"
            android:textSize="18px" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

android:layout_width="" and android:layout_height="" must be fixed " fill_parent" or "wrap_content"

try this one

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >     
   <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25px"
        android:text="India is best"                     
        android:layout_weight="2" />
</TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using Table layout what sandhya proposed.
Apart from that there are few thing which may cause problem are,

1). If you are providing weightsum then you must divide weight equally to child element,

2)if you are using child weight as horizontal then you must give then give width as 0dp and if vertical then height  should b 0dp. Its give better performance.

3)avoid hardcoding values like in layout_height=28dp as your code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="India is best"
                    android:textSize="18dp" >
                </EditText>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="India is best"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="India is best"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="India is best"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have edited my answer, this provide exactly what you needed